# Adding a new ending date column derived from the difference between two start dates in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a data frame that consists of people and address data for each person. There is also a "STARTING_DATE" column that indicates when each person began living at a particular address. Some people have multiple addresses which means multiple starting dates. What I would like to do is create an "ENDING_DATE" column that calculates the difference between two starting dates and selects the date prior to the new starting date.

Please see my example below (this is what I would like the output to be):

```
PersonID       Address                Starting_Date       Ending_Date
1              1st Residence           2010-02-05         
2              1st Residence           2012-05-18         2014-09-22
2              2nd Residence           2014-09-23
3              1st Residence           2014-04-10         2017-07-21
3              2nd Residence           2017-07-22
```

As you can see in the 'Ending_Date' column, it shows for Persons 2 and 3 a date that occurs one day prior to the next row's "Starting_Date" value. I have used the `lubridate` package in R to  calculate the answer, though I am unfortunately not getting the answer I would like.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

addr.data <- addr.data %>%
    group_by(PersonID, Starting_Date) %>%
    mutate(Ending_Date = max(Starting_Date) - days(1))
```

This is just returning the date prior to the max date based on each PersonID grouping if they have multiple start dates. How can I calculate the difference between two distinct start dates and return the date prior to the new 'Start_Date' column?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you group by 'Starting_Date', there would be a single row as showed in the example

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @TarJae The expected output is the example data frame I posted. I will edit my post to indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr`

```
addr.data %>% group_by(PersonID) %>%
              mutate(Address = as.numeric(str_extract(Address, '^\\d+')),
                     Ending_date = ifelse(Address == lag(Address)+1, lag(Ending_date) + 1, Ending_date))
```